# Mean of index values in Pandas dataframe following groupby()

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
myDF = pd.DataFrame({'quarter':['Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4','Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4','Q1','Q2','Q3','Q4'],
                     'year':[2018,2018,2018,2018,2019,2019,2019,2019,2020,2020,2020,2020]})
```

which looks like:

```
   quarter  year
0       Q1  2018
1       Q2  2018
2       Q3  2018
3       Q4  2018
4       Q1  2019
5       Q2  2019
6       Q3  2019
7       Q4  2019
8       Q1  2020
9       Q2  2020
10      Q3  2020
11      Q4  2020
```

I can calculate the mean of the index values:

```
print(np.mean(myDF.index))
5.5
```

...but I would like to produce a list of the mean index values for each year.

I can create a new variable based on index values and find the mean of those values as follows:

```
myDF['idx'] = myDF.index
print(myDF.groupby('year')['idx'].apply(list))
print(myDF.groupby('year')['idx'].apply(np.mean).tolist())
```

to produce:

```
year
2018      [0, 1, 2, 3]
2019      [4, 5, 6, 7]
2020    [8, 9, 10, 11]
Name: idx, dtype: object


[1.5, 5.5, 9.5]
```

However, I don't seem to be able to manipulate the index values directly. I've tried applying various versions of the above to DataFrameGroupBy objects but I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'index'
```

So, whilst I have a solution, creating a new variable based on the index seems a bit redundant. Can the required list of means be created without the need to alter the original dataframe?

Comment: `myDF.groupby('year').apply(lambda x: np.mean(x.index))`?

Comment: You generally act on columns when you aggregate, so the simplest solution is to turn it into a column with `.reset_index`: `myDF.reset_index().groupby('year')['index'].mean()`

Comment: @ALollz Your solution is equivalent to the solution I posted in the question, namely creating a column of the index values and then using groupby(). But with your solution, the column is not created permanently, which is good.

Comment: @QuangHoang That's a very nice solution - thanks for responding.

Comment: Yeah, `groupby` really only acts on the columns at least with all the built-in implementations. You can use a `groupby.apply`, but those become slow loops so it's best to avoid that. `reset_index` might not be ideal if you need to assign something _back_ to the DataFrame, like `.groupby(...)['index'].transform('sum')` because now alignment is all wonky so best to assign a separate column so the original index is preserved for alignment (like you did)